# html/css: Making a table element inside of a button selectable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an element that looks as following (https://jsfiddle.net/e176dosp/1/):

```
<button>
  My Button
  <table>
    <thead align="left">
    <tr>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody align="left">
    <tr>
      <td>Soil group</td>
      <td>Cambisols</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</button>
```

I would like to be able to have the table element be separate from the button, meaning that I can click on the My Button text to press the button but also select the text from the table below, while still having the table be part of the button class. I have tried to find ways with javascript and css to "undo" the button class in the table element, or to find classes that override the button onclick behaviour but only found solutions on how to remove css classes that are not inbuilt, such as button or table.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need it as a button? Seems that it would be much easier to just style a div to look like a button then set the aria label to reflect its purpose

Comment: If you want a table inside something , you shouldn't call or (do) a button . Make it with div

Comment: Kinda confused with your usage of the word "class" as there is none in markup. Please explain what a "button class" is. Is it `class Button`?

Comment: Would suggest you redesign the UI. Separate out the table and button.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'selecting the text from the table'? There's nothing to stop actual selection (in the normal, highlighting, sense) but you can't have any interactive content inside a button so the table elements can't be clickable for example.

Comment: "*remove css classes that are not inbuilt*" - by "inbuilt", do you mean `<button>`?   Just change your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, OP requests that a button (separate from the table) when clicked will select the text of the table. I suspect the ultimate goal is to have that button copy the text of the table to clipboard. If so, review the following example.

***Details commented in example***

```js
/**
 * @desc Copy the text of a given tag to the clipboard.
 * @param {string<CSSString>/object<DOM>} selector - The 
 *        HTML element to extract text from
 * @param {boolean} pre - Option to copy text preformatted
 *        false (@default) - text is partially formatted
 *        true - text is preformatted
 */
function textCopy(selector, pre = false) {
  let target = typeof selector == "string" ? document.querySelector(selector) : selector;
  let text = !pre ? target.innerText : target.textContent;
  navigator.clipboard.writeText('');
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text.normalize());
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  textCopy('table');
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<button>Copy</button>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Soil group</td>
      <td>Cambisols</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<textarea rows='3' cols='30' placeholder='Paste Here'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the `user-select` property.

```js
    function fun1(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
    function fun2(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log("My Button");
    }
```

```css
    button {
      padding: 1px 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .sel {
      background-color: red;
      -moz-user-select: text;
      -webkit-user-select: text;
      -ms-user-select: text;
      user-select: text;
      padding: 0 3px;
    }
```

```html
    <button onclick="fun2(event)">
      My Button
      <table class="sel" onclick="fun1(event)">
        <thead align="left">
          <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Value</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody align="left">
          <tr>
            <td>Soil group</td>
            <td>Cambisols</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </button>
```